# ASP.Net Owin Authentication.SignOut not redirecting user via RedirectUri on sign out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, azure-active-directory, owin

*-- An edit was made below - the revised question is at the bottom:*

I have a multi-tenancy application, which uses Azure AD to authenticate users.

The application when signing out, appears to ignore the `.RedirectUri` attribute in the lifecycle of the signout process. When initally signing out, I can see the application initially redirects correctly here:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={REDIRECT](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=%7BREDIRECT) URI} (and trailing QueryString variables).

Once this process completes, the app redirects to the below location and sits without ever redirecting back:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession

This gives the user the standard "user has logged out, it's a good idea to close all browser windows".

How can I prevent this last redirect, and ensure the logout redirects back to the application?

```vb
Dim callbackUrl As String = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) & Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/aservices/logout_response.aspx")
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
        New AuthenticationProperties() With {.RedirectUri = callbackUrl},
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

**EDIT:** It appears that this does work from using a `<asp:LoginStatus>` control with the `LogoutAction="Redirect"` property set. How can I replicate this behaviour in the codebehind?

Comment: Have you tried `Session.Abandon()` in this  LoginStatus control ?Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524310%28v%3dvs.90%29)

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm using ASP.net mvc.  There are no web controls with mvc so a codebehind solution is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving answer from comments,

You need to tried `Session.Abandon()` in this *LoginStatus* control . Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524310%28v%3Dvs.90%29)